# What did Kernighan & Ritchie mean by 'Floating-point computations may now be done in single precision' in the new ANSI C standard?

Tags: c, floating-point

On page 2 of *The C programming Language* by Kernighan & Ritchie, 2nd edition, in says that in the 'ANSI C' standard (as opposed to 'K&R C', which was defined in the first edition):

> Floating-point computations may now be done in single precision.

What did they mean by that?

From Wikipedia and various Google search queries I've found that single precision in C means the 'float' data type (as opposed to 'double' data type which is a 'double precision'), but 'float' also appears in the first edition.

Comment: While the original language may have had a `float` datatype, I suspect it required everything to be converted to double precision internally when doing calculations, then reduced to single precision when storing in the variables. Now calculations involving only `float` will stay at single precision.

Comment: So `floatvar3 = floatvar1 + floatvar2;` used to be equivalent to `floatvar3 = (float)((double)floatvar1 + (double)floatvar2)`

Comment: Note: `float` and `double` aren't necessarily IEEE single-precision and IEEE double-precision numbers. What they are is up to the compiler, although largely dictated by the hardware. That said, it should be the case in x86- and x86-64-based environments.

Comment: Note that the issues here are deeper than they look.  At first, the strategy of "convert everything to `double`, do the math as `double`, then convert back to `float` at the end if necessary" looks a lot like the analogous strategy for bumping all the integral types up to at least `int`.  But it turns out that doing all your calculations (that is, keeping all your intermediate results) in double precision is much, much better for floating-point accuracy and stability, so is recommended by numerical analysts.  Also, at least on machines with a dedicated FPU, double precision isn't much slower.

Comment: On the PDP-11, where C was born, it wasn't at all convenient to do calculations using any mixture of single- and double-precision.  There was one set of floating-point instructions, and a global mode bit that controlled whether those instructions performed single- or double-precision calculations.  So C executables, at least, just always set the bit to "use double precision" and left it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are talking largely about what we now call the "usual arithmetic conversions" (C17 6.3.1.8).  This is a pattern of type conversions that is automatically applied to the operands of arithmetic operators. The stated primary objective is to bring the operands to a common type, but they also serve to reduce the number of distinct data types for which arithmetic operations must be implemented, and perhaps other purposes.

In the first edition of K&R, these are described on page 41, with the first provision being that (regardless of the other operand),

> `char` and `short` are converted to `int`, and `float` is converted to `double`.

In that version of C, then, it is impossible to express a floating-point arithmetic operation performed at single precision (i.e. as a `float`), because `float` operands are converted to `double` whether you like it or not.  For example, K&R 1ed specifies that this ...

```
    float x = 1;
    float y = 1;
    float z = x + y;
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
    float x = 1;
    float y = 1;
    float z = (double) x + (double) y;
```

All versions of standard C still specify that integer arithmetic operands of lower "integer conversion rank" than `int` are automatically converted to `int` or `unsigned int`, depending on various details.  However, no version of standard C contained the K&R 1ed provision that `float` operands are automatically promoted to `double`.  A `float` operand will be promoted to `double` if the other operand is a `double`, but not if the other is a `float` or any integer type.

Of course, that may be a distinction without much difference.  The language spec doesn't have much to say about the details of floating point computation, so it is not necessarily the case that operations on `float`s behave any differently than by promoting the operands to `double`.  In standard C, however, whether they do is a detail of the implementation, not a semantic requirement of the language.

Comment: The text `Notice that all floats in an expression are converted to double; all floating point arithmetic in C is done in double precision.` on page 41 answers my question. Marking this answer as 'accepted'. Thank you.